# Delivering replicated transactions in SQL Server transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I had seen this message in no. of replication cases but never got to know what is the exact cause behind this message and what troubleshooting to be done to know what is going on. What I want to know is a definitive guide of what needs to be done in such cases.

1. What scripts to run to check what command is executing?
2. What agent parameters to change?
3. How to check if there are any big transactions causing this?

I searched many blogs but didn't get any concrete answer. Hoping that will get it here.

Comment: does [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/139768/8783) help you.

Comment: @Kin Thanks! It does help. Do have any details on what parameters to change and when? Any example would be great.